# Split HTML into pages with no lines cut in half

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, epub

Does anybody know how iBooks splits the HTML files in an EPUB book into multiple pages so that no lines of text is cut in half?

I've managed to display eBooks in a `UIWebView`, but often the lines of text get cut in half at the top and/or bottom of the view.

(I would post an image to show what I mean, but I have too few reputation points. But hopefully you get the idea.)

Comment: In cases like this, if you can post a link to an image, somebody with enough rep could include the image for you. I like this as a workaround as the editor has the chance to moderate the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on iBooks, but I believe it tweaks `UIWebView` so only a page worth of content is displayed in the view. You could try this:

1. load the full HTML without displaying it
2. set the text selection from the start of the top line to the end of the last line in the view
3. then trim the content at the end of the selection

Comment: I think your avatar works incredibly well with the bobblehead power up :)